# How to call a method based on a specific derived class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I was trying to understand how the weak pointer member (using the visual studio 2013 C++ compiler)

```
mutable weak_ptr<_Ty> _Wptr
```

from the template class `enable_shared_from_this` was initialized when a `std::shared_ptr<_Ty>` was created out of an object that derived from it. For this purpose I traced the code from a simple code that created a `std::shared_ptr<_Ty>` with the template function `std::make_share<_Ty>`

I found that the initialization of `_Wptr` proceeded when the compiler called the method `_Enable_shared` within the base class `_Ref_count_del_alloc`.

Now 2 template methods were defined for this purpose. One method is defined when the `_Ty` class is derived from `enable_shared_from_this`. This is the method:

```
template<class _Ty>
inline void _Enable_shared(_Ty *_Ptr, _Ref_count_base *_Refptr,
    typename _Ty::_EStype * = 0)
{   // reset internal weak pointer
if (_Ptr)
    _Do_enable(_Ptr,
        (enable_shared_from_this<typename _Ty::_EStype>*)_Ptr, _Refptr);
}
```

The second method is defined when the `_Ty` class **is not** derived from `enable_shared_from_this`. This is the method:

```
inline void _Enable_shared(const volatile void *, const volatile void *)
{   
    // not derived from enable_shared_from_this; do nothing
}
```

The question I have is how the C++ compiler is able to resolve which method to use? Beside I would have expected both methods to be instantiated at compile time and have a compile error if the class is not derived from `enable_shared_from_this`. Yet the compiler seems to select only one method to instantiate and the appropriate method.

Comment: What you sloppily call "method" is actually a *function template*. It's possible to define templates that are not instantiated. Function template specializations that would be ill-formed for a choice of deduced arguments do not participate in overload resolution ("sfinae").

Comment: A better approach to understanding how the pointer is initialized, is to just implement an enable_shared facility yourself. Looking at others' unexplained code you just get bogged down in arbitrary details.

Answer (score 1):

After digging in the code I found that the key point to understand how this is done is through function template specialization as Kerry SB pointed. Since `_EStype` is only defined within the `enable_shared_from_this` base template class then the compiler is able to select between either `_Enable_shared` function template according to the less ill-formed calling from the arguments.

This is well explained in the following post of Herb Sutter:

[Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: It's not really function template specialisation; it's actually an application of [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).

Comment: Thank for pointing this and provide the link to SFINAE. That's exactly what is done with the code. Good link and explanation